# Why is phpmyadmin giving me inconsistent query results?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to write some queries to get the id of one of my tables by name. The trouble is that the query only returns rows for some values and not others. Here are some examples and the results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `ENVIRONMENT` 
WHERE ENV_NAME =  "Artist"
```

Returns

[image]

But if I try

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `ENVIRONMENT` 
WHERE ENV_NAME =  "test"
```

The query returns an empty row. Here is all of my data in the table

[image]

It seems like something that is too simple to mess up so maybe there is a nuance of phpmyadmin that I am unaware of. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried single quotes?...id also confirm env_name doesnt have any whitespace in it.  you can confirm this with SELECT * 
FROM  `ENVIRONMENT` 
WHERE ENV_NAME LIKE  'test%'

Comment: I have tried `WHERE ENV_NAME LIKE 't%'` and `WHERE ENV_NAME LIKE 'test%'` and neither one works unfortunately

Comment: Meaning that `WHERE ENV_NAME LIKE 't%'` returns nothing?

Comment: Yes exactly. The query executes but returns an empty set. It is strange because running the select without the where returns everything including test

Comment: What's the collation for `ENV_NAME`? If it's something quite odd, I suppose that could affect MySQL's ability to match your search. Also, what's the data type for that column?